# Magento Change Currency Separator Punctuation

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view, currency

Current Price Display in Indonesian Currency: RP3.075.167,50
How do I change to display in RP3,075,167.50

```
<symbols>
        <decimal>,</decimal>
        <group>.</group>
    </symbols>
    <currencyFormats>
        <currencyFormatLength>
            <currencyFormat>
                <pattern>¤#,##0.00</pattern>
            </currencyFormat>
        </currencyFormatLength>
    </currencyFormats>
```

Chris

Comment: anyone able to offer any insights on this?